# Android Studio -- Use Gradle with the 'traditional' ordering of files

Tags: android, ant, gradle, android-studio

I am building a project with Gradle, but, to maintain consistency with my coworkers' use of the Ant build system, I need to keep the old file structure.  How do I refactor my project/file structure to the traditional one?

I thought this would be a common question, but I could not find any answers.  Can Android Studio help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I refactor my project/file structure to the traditional one?

Start with the traditional one in the first place. Don't change the files -- change `build.gradle`.

All of my CWAC libraries are published this way, using the legacy project directory structure, but with a `build.gradle` file (based on the one you can export from Eclipse) that teaches Gradle for Android where everything is.

For example, here is the relevant piece of the `build.gradle` file for my `WakefulIntentService`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Here, we are configuring the `main` `sourceset`, from a Gradle perspective, telling it where all the different types of "source" come from. Most things, like the Java code, come from the `src/` directory in the project, for example.

Some of this is unused in my projects (e.g., pointing the `debug` and `release` build types to look for their custom sourcesets off of a `build-types/` directory), but I left it there from what Eclipse exported.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, as always!  In my particular case, I imported in Eclipse, and moved some stuff manually, which was pretty easy to do.